# Stylize multiple layers with same coordinates GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have many light buoys and if a buoy have two colours, I have two layers buoys with their different attributes like this:
[image: the first color is white so the circle is black]

However, I can't stylize the second layer with the second colour (green). Only the first layer is read and never the others...

You can see a piece of my stylesheet:

```
      <se:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter>

            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>COLOUR</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>200000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:PointSymbolizer>
          <se:Graphic>
            <!--Well known marker fallback-->
            <se:Mark>
              <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
              <se:Fill>
                <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0</se:SvgParameter>
              </se:Fill>
              <se:Stroke>
                <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
                <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
              </se:Stroke>
            </se:Mark>
            <se:Size>100</se:Size>
            <se:Rotation>180</se:Rotation>
            <se:Displacement>
              <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
              <se:DisplacementY>0</se:DisplacementY>
            </se:Displacement>        
          </se:Graphic>
        </se:PointSymbolizer>
      </se:Rule>

      <!--Colour = 3 ->green -->
      <se:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>COLOUR</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>200000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:PointSymbolizer>
          <se:Graphic>
            <!--Well known marker fallback-->
            <se:Mark>
              <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
              <se:Fill>
                <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0</se:SvgParameter>
              </se:Fill>
              <se:Stroke>
                <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#00CF03</se:SvgParameter>
                <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
              </se:Stroke>
            </se:Mark>
            <se:Size>100</se:Size>
            <se:Rotation>180</se:Rotation>
            <se:Displacement>
              <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
              <se:DisplacementY>0</se:DisplacementY>
            </se:Displacement>        
          </se:Graphic>
        </se:PointSymbolizer>
      </se:Rule>
```

Comment: It is probably drawing them both one exactly on top of the other we can't tell which order those 2 will draw because you haven't shown the `COLOUR` attribute